# How to generate RSpec test cases for each value of ActiveModel's Inclusion validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, activemodel

I've got that simple ActiveModel class holding a string field on which I defined an *inclusion* validator:

```
$ rails generate model Person name:string gender:string
```

```ruby
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female unknown) }
end
```

Now I'm writing some RSpec test cases, which should represent an always up-to-date docu of that model.

```ruby
describe Person, type: :model do
  context 'attributes' do
    context 'gender' do
      it 'allows "male"' { ... }
      it 'allows "female"' { ... }
      it 'allows "unknown"' { ... }
    end
  end
end
```

How can I automatically generate these three test cases from the list given to the validator?
I know I can get the validator with `Person.validators_on(:gender).first`, but not how to query that validator instance for the enumerable of the `in`-option.

The ultimate goal is to replace the three test cases by something like

```ruby
query_validator_for_in_enum().each do |valid_gender|
  it "allows '#{valid_gender}'" { ... }
end
```

---

*Rationale*: I don't want to create a separate table for 'gender' to workaround this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to check out [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem.

Adding this kind of checks would be as easy as:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:gender).in_array(%w(male female unknown)) }
```

I would create a constant in the model:

```
GENDERS = %w(male female unknown)
```

and use it in specs:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:gender).in_array(Person::GENDERS) }
```

Comment: Right, I could just copy&paste the same enumerable from the model definition into the specs. However, that way I always have to remember to also update the spec when I alter the model validation enum.

Comment: Not actually, I would go with constant `GENDERS` to only update it in one place - model. Tests are left without the need to be changed

Comment: m( Of cause, a constant `GENDERS`. That solution is too simple that I thought of. Thanks a lot!